# How can I cut a string in C?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: greeting message name\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char greeting[20];
    char *name = argv[2];

    // Your code goes here
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
        if (i < 20) {
            greeting[i] = argv[1][i];
        }
        else {
            greeting[i] = '\0';
        }
    }

    int greeting_len = strlen(greeting);
    strcat(greeting, " ");
    strncat(greeting, name, 20-greeting_len-2);

    printf("%s\n", greeting);
    return 0;
}
```

In this practice, I am required to concatenate the two command line arguments, which are `greeting` and `name`, together and separated by a space. What's more, the greeting and the string after concentrated cannot be longer than 20 characters.

When I run
`./a.out "Good morninggggggggggggggggggg" "Emmanuel"`, there is an error saying

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: By making `greeting[]` larger?  Just a thought.

Comment: If the combined strings can be 20 characters long, you need to declare `greeting[21]`. You need space for the trailing null. Also, `strncat()` will not add a null if it hits the limit, you need to add that yourself.

Comment: Nope, greeting[20] is fixed. I can't modify it.

Comment: `greeting[20]` can't contain 20 characters, only 19 plus the null. Unless they're including the null byte when they say that it can't be longer than 20.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, maybe I misunderstand it. It should be 19 characters then.

Comment: So what do you want to do? You don't have more than 19 characters, so that's all you get bro.

Comment: `"Good morninggggggggggggggggggg"` is definitely more than 19. I want to cut it out.

Comment: regarding: `       if (i < 20) {
            greeting[i] = argv[1][i];
        }
        else {
            greeting[i] = '\0';
        }`  In C, offsets into an array are 0...(number of elements in array -1)  So  the posted code overflows the array size, resulting in undefined behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `message` argument is longer than 20 characters, your first loop will write outside the bounds of `greeting`. The `if` statement doesn't stop the loop, it keeps going, but assigns null bytes instead of `argv[1][i]`.

And if the `message` argument fits into `greeting`, you never add a null byte at all. The loop stops after copying the last character, not including the null terminator.

You can simply use `strncpy()`, and then set the last byte of `greeting` to a null byte.

```
strncpy(greeting, argv[1], sizeof greeting);
greeting[sizeof greeting - 1] = '\0';
```

You need to check if you've hit the limit before adding the space:

```
if (greeting_len < 18) {
    greeting[greeting_len] = ' ';
    greeting[greeting_len+1] = '\0';
    greeting_len++;
}
if (greeting_len < 18) {
    strncat(greeting, name, 19-greeting_len);
}
```

But if you can use `snprintf()` it's all much easier:

```
snprintf(greeting, sizeof greeting, "%s %s", argv[1], name);
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for (and handles) errors
4. has no openings for undefined behavior nor buffer overflows
5. places a space between `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    if (argc != 3) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: greeting message name\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    char *greeting = malloc( strlen( argv[1] ) + strlen( argv[2] ) +1 +1 );
    if( !greeting )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    strcpy( greeting, argv[1] );
    strcat( greeting, " " );
    strcat( greeting, argv[2] );


    printf("%s\n", greeting);

    free( greeting );
    return 0;
}
```